# C# list<item> group by year then by month

Tags: c#

I have a List and Item contains one property called Created which is DateTime.

How can I group the items by Year then by month in descending order like this?

```
2015
    August
    July
    June
    May
    April
    March
    February
    January
2014
    December
    November
    October
........
```

Here is my approach:

```
var grouped = myList.GroupBy(t => t.Created.Year).Select(t => new { Year = t.Key, Months = t.GroupBy(x => x.Created.Month) });
```

Comment: Put `.ThenBy(t => t.Created.Month)` after `GroupBy(t => t.Created.Year)`

Comment: `OrderBy(..).ThenBy(..)`  is not valid...

Comment: or use `GroupBy(t=>new {t.Created.Year, t.Created.Month})` to group by both at once

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if it suits, but I would do something like this:

```
var grouped = myList.GroupBy(t => t.Created.Year)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Year = t.Key,
        Months = t.GroupBy(x => x.Created.Month)
            .Select(y => new
            {
                Month = y.Key,
                Values = y.ToList()
             })
    });
```